# How to prove that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ without using the Binomial Theorem?

Tags: derivatives, binomial-theorem

How does one show that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x^n =nx^{n-1}$ without resorting to the Binomial Theorem?

Edited :

I'm interested in this approach as I've been tinkering with the proof for the Binomial Theorem using Taylor Series but then later realized that I've assumed $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ which I have proven earlier using the Binomial Theorem itself. So the proof ended up being circular in nature. I'm trying to circumvent that by proving it without the Binomial Theorem. Link to question : [Binomial Theorem Proof from Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394011/binomial-theorem-proof-from-taylor-series)

Comment: The product rule and induction?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeProofs.aspx

Comment: Why you do not want to use the Binomial theorem. That is the most easy process and follows by the definition of Riemann integration. Please give more reasons for your interest @Chung Ren Khoo.

Comment: We could use logs. We could use the multivariate chain rule, with $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = x_1\cdot x_2 \cdots x_n$.  None of these are really *easier* that the binomial theorem, so its unclear if any of that would be useful to you.

Comment: @TRUSKI : I've been trying to prove the Binomial Theorem from Taylor's Series but later realized I made the assumption that the derivative of $x^n=nx^{n-1}$ which uses the binomial theorem which I was trying to prove in the first place. So it ended up being a circular argument. Link to my previous question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394011/binomial-theorem-proof-from-taylor-series

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo The binomial theorem in the discrete case can be proven with elementary means (e.g., combinatorics or induction).

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo that kind of context is a helpful thing to include in the question statement.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Fair enough. I shall edit my question statement to reflect that.

Comment: @TedShifrin This is a useful comment because transferring the idea of a derivative to other contexts, $Dx=1$ and $Dxy=xDy+yDx$ are taken as defining properties, and this can work even when limit-based definitions are not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
S=1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{n-1}
$$
is a geometric series; multiply $S$ by $y$ to get
$$
Sy=y+y^2+\cdots+y^{n-1}+y^n
$$
Subtract $Sy$ from $S$ to get
$$
Sy-S=y^{n}-1    
$$
Therefore
$$
y^n-1=(y-1)(1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{n-1})
$$
Put $y=\frac{x+h}{x}$ (provided $x\not=0$) to get
$$
\frac{(x+h)^n}{x^n}-1=\left(\frac{x+h}{x}-1\right)
\left(
1+\frac{x+h}{x}+\frac{(x+h)^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{(x+h)^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}
\right)\tag{*}
$$
Multiply both sides by $x^n$ to get
$$
(x+h)^n-x^n=h(x^{n-1}+(x+h)x^{n-2}+(x+h)^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+(x+h)^{n-1})
$$

We wish to find the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^n$ from first principle. If $x=0$, then
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^n}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h^{n-1}=0
$$
If $x\not=0$, then
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(x^{n-1}+(x+h)x^{n-2}+(x+h)^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+(x+h)^{n-1})}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}(x^{n-1}+(x+h)x^{n-2}+(x+h)^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+(x+h)^{n-1})\\
&=x^{n-1}+xx^{n-2}+x^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+x^{n-1}\\
&=\underbrace{x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x^{n-1}}_{n\text{ copies}}\\
&=nx^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do you mind elaborating this line please :

$(x+h)^n-x^n = h(x^{n-1}+(x+h)x^{n-2}+...+(x+h)^{n-1})$

Not sure how you managed to get the bit on the RHS. Thanks.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Sure. You want to multiply both sides of (*) by $x^n$; on the right hand side we multiply $\left(\frac{x+h}{x}-1\right)$ by $x$ which gives you $x+h-x=h$ and you multiply $\left(
1+\frac{x+h}{x}+\frac{(x+h)^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{(x+h)^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}
\right)$ by $x^{n-1}$ to get $x^{n-1}+(x+h)x^{n-2}+(x+h)^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+(x+h)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Very interesting technique. Fracturing $x^n$ into $x$ and $x^{n-1}$ so as to leave the brackets undisturbed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious. What was the intuition behind this proof? Why is a geometric series of this form a sensible starting point? Masterfully done btw.

Comment: @user472047 "Subtract $Sy$ from $S$" should read "Subtract $S$ from $Sy$".

Answer (score 5):

$(x^{n+1})'=(x\times x^n)'
=x(x^n)'+(x^n)
=xnx^{n-1}+x^n
=nx^n+x^n=(n+1)x^n$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^n = e^{n \log x}$$
Thus, $$\frac{dx^n}{dx} =e^{n\log x}\cdot \frac{n}{x}=nx^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\dfrac{d(x^n)}{dx}_{(\text{at } x=a)}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-r}a^r$$
Now set $x=a$ to find $$x^{n-1-r}a^r=a^{n-1}$$ for each $r$ such that $0\le r\le n-1$.

Comment: Your first equality is wrong. It should say $\displaystyle {} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a}.$ And after the second "equals" sign, you should also have "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}$". $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Thanks, really basic mistake

Comment: How did you go from $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$ to $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-r} a^r$ ?