# Proof that $(x\times x^n)'=x(x^n)'+x^n$?

Tags: derivatives

Seen in martycohen's answer to [How to prove that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ without using the Binomial Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394033).

Comment: It’s the product rule.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, the chain of comments has become a referendum on the validity of the product rule in elementary calculus. The OP  finds one of Newton's arguments convincing. Someone should point out that Newton never proved anything about calculus. Nor did anyone else before around the end of the nineteenth century, when people like Cauchy and Weierstrass  finally gave  coherent *definitions* for the relevant concepts.

It's not that hard, and  in particular there are no errors  in the proof. I can say that because I know the proof very well.

> > **Start Here.** If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=a$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded in the interval $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$.

Proof: By definition there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-a|<1$ if $0<|x-p|<\delta$. So if $x\in(p-\delta,p+\delta)$ and $x\ne p$ then $$|f(x)|=|a+(f(x)-a)|\le|a|+|f(x)-a|<|a|+1.$$So for *every* $x\in(p-\delta,p+\delta)$ we have $$|f(x)|\le\max(|f(p)|,|a|+1).$$

> > **Lemma** If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0$ and $g$ is bounded in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$ then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=0$.

Proof: Say $|g|\le M$ in that interval.  Let $\epsilon>0$. By definition   there exists $\delta_1\in(0,\delta)$such that $$|f(x)|<\epsilon/M\quad(0<|x-p|<\delta_1).$$So $0<|x-p|<\delta_1$ implies $$|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)||g(x)|<\frac\epsilon MM=\epsilon.$$

> > **Cor 1.** If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=0$.

Proof: The **Start Here** shows that $f$ is bounded in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$, so the lemma implies qed.

> > **Cor2** If $f$ is differentiable at $p$ then $f$ is continuous at $p$.

Proof: If $h\ne0$ then $$f(p+h)-f(p)=\frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}hh.$$Sine $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}h=f'(p)$ and $\lim_{h\to0}h=0$, the previous corollary  shows that $\lim_{h\to0}(f(p+h)-f(p))=0$.

> > **Cor3** If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=b$ then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=ab$.

Proof: This one uses a little trick:

> > **Trick** $AB-ab=A(B-b)+(A-a)b$.

So $$f(x)g(x)-ab=f(x)(g(x)-b)+(f(x)-a)b,$$and now Cor 1 shows that $$\lim_{x\to p}(f(x)g(x)-ab)=0+0.$$

> > **Theorem** If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$ then so is $fg$, with $(fg)'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$.

Proof: We use the trick one more time: $$\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}h=f(x+h)\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h+\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}hg(x).$$So Cor 2 and Cor 3 show that$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h\\&+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\lim_{h\to0}g(x)\\&=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x).\end{align}$$

No, I don't have that whole proof memorized. What *is* in long-term storage in my head is the fact that the **trick** is going to be important; the rest is routine details (ok, routine only because I have a lot of experience with this sort of thing.)

You say you want to be a mathematician. Great. Learning to spot errors and gaps  is important:

> > **Exercise** Identify the ("obvious", easily proved) fact about limits used several times above without proof (in fact used withhout being even stated)..

Comment: The comment chain wasn't a referendum on the validity of the product rule. I can explain what it was about if you like, but I don't suppose you're interested. I recognise the end of your proof from the wiki linked to in the comment chain above (now at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98213/discussion-on-answer-by-j-g-proof-that-x-times-xnxxnxn); overall the proof looks like it would take me some time to chew through. I see you've put a good deal of care and clarity into it, which encourages me to make the effort. Thanks for that.

Comment: I haven't finished reading and digesting yet, but is the fact about limits uniqueness?

Comment: @mjc No. I suppose I may have used that, but what I have in mind is different.

Comment: @mjc If $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exist then $\lim(f+g)=\lim f+\lim  g$.

Comment: OK, thanks. I probably wouldn't have got that quickly.

Comment: What's the difference between $a$ and $f(p)$?

Comment: @mjc The difference is $a-f(p)$. I take it you're referring to one of the places where I said $\lim{x\to p}f(x)=a$. In fact  the value of $f((p)$ is completely and totally irrelevant to the value of that limit. (If the two happen to be equal then by definition $f$ is _continuous at $p$_.)

Comment: @mjc I assumed you'd taken calculus, sorry. Define $f(x)=0$ for  $x\ne0$, $f(0)=1$. Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$  even though $f(0)=1$. If this is not obvious you need to study up on what $\lim$ means...

Comment: @mjc You need to understand a little bit about limits before you have a chance with things like this proof. (And sorry, but when you ask what's the difference between $a$ and $f(p)$ it's evident you don't understand "the first thing" about limits.) Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)

Comment: I have what may be an unusual learning style. I don't always work from the bottom up. and I find using a case study like this to work backward to its elements quite fruitful. I've read definitions of limits before, and I'm finding working through this proof useful for getting a grip on them. At present I would find starting on p1 of a calculus book and going through it in order boring and demotivating, since being spoon-fed can't replicate creative discovery.

Comment: @mjc Great. In your quest for understanding make certain not to miss the hugely important fact that the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ has absolutely nothing to do with the value (if any) of $f(a)$.

Comment: I will work towards understanding that idea in all its implications.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $(uv)^\prime=uv^\prime+u^\prime v$. Now use $x^\prime=1$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98213/discussion-on-answer-by-j-g-proof-that-x-times-xnxxnxn).